# Split and non splitting short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, exact-sequence

Please explain that in this,

[image]

Why the first sequence is split exact while other is non-split and exact?

Comment: The definition of the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ being exact is that $B \cong A \times C$. Now, $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/q \mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z$, but $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: @fish: Your comment is misleading. The definition you give is not the definition of “exactness”. “being exact is that” should have been “being split is that”.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey vital parts of your question. Images are not easily searchable, and render your question inaccessible to anyone using a screen reader.  Please take the time to correctly type up your question.  You may find the [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is split exact iff $B\cong A\oplus C$ and the given maps correspond to the inclusion $A\to A\oplus C$ and the projection $A\oplus C\to C$ under the isomorphism between them.

Note that $\Bbb Z_{pq} \cong\Bbb Z_p\oplus \Bbb Z_q$, say, because of the Chinese remainder theorem, while $\Bbb Z_{p^2} \not\cong \Bbb Z_p\oplus \Bbb Z_p$, say, because the former contains an element of order $p^2$ while the latter does not.

Comment: So we don"t need to even check exactness in this?..or will that condition exactness as well..if i do need to check exactness,what should i do?

Comment: In the second case, you need to prove exactness, yes.

Comment: So that condition does imply exactness?..therefore we don't need to prove exactness in the first case...right?...n how will we show exactness in second case?..please tell

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Just observe that the kernel of the second map is $p\Bbb Z_p\le\Bbb Z_p$, and the same is the image of the first map.

Comment: So the first sequence is split exact no matter what the R-homomorohisms are?

Comment: No, the maps do matter. You should try to prove it's exact. Nevertheless, it follows from the condition given in my answer.

Comment: But where did we use the definition of maps in that condition